# Can't extend root partition even after booting from LiveUSB

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ext4, unallocated

After doing some research on how to extend Ubuntu root partition, I tried to extend it using the GParted from a liveUSB session of Ubuntu. But I couldn't extend it. When I right click on my root partition and select resize/move, it doesn't offer me the unallocated space. Here is the screenshot of GParted showing my current partition structure:

[image: GParted Screenshot]

Somewhere on AskUbuntu I read that unallocated space has to be inserted into the Extended partition. I don't know if that's true and I don't know how to move it into the Extended partition. Please help me, I spent the whole day behind this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to understand that sda5, sda6, sda7 and sda8 are inside sda3.

After that it looks simpler.

1. Boot from LiveCD. Do not mount any partitions by clicking them.
2. Run `sudo swapoff -a`
3. Expand sda3 left.
4. Move sda5, sda6, sda7 left.
5. Expand sda8 left.

Do not forget to press "Apply" button.

After you do it you also need to update grub this way.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo update-grub
exit
```

Comment: Am I not supposed to turn the swap on again?

Comment: This command turns swap off only while booted from LiveCD. If after normal reboot it is off, then turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you want 2 different partitions for 2 different windows OS's and Ubuntu. Why don't you format the whole disk, divide your 300GB into 3 partitions only ..100gb each. I agree this is an overambitious partition configuration. I have 3 partitions 2 for windows and 1 for linux, I always use the 2nd NTFS as storage so that every time I have to reinstall virus prone windows I never loose any personal files. Lastly ext4 is the file format for ubuntu not ntfs windows (networking technology file systems), try change the file format first and then resize, you will also need a swap file for ubuntu a 4th partition sda4, your in gparted but you can also the install cd partition manager, while installing, formatting the whole drive may cause data loss, so off course back up to an external HDD first, but I guarantee you 100% reformatting always fixes everything..lol, your going to spend hours typing mnt commands when reformatting will have you up and running in 30 minutes

Answer (score -1):

Your partitioning scheme seems overambitious, but here goes. The structure of partitions on the disk has to be kept simple, since the BIOS has to be able to find something to boot. Thus, the restriction that you can only expand/move a partition to adjacent free space and cannot have fancy split partitions. Thus, if you MUST expand `/` (mounted on `/dev/sda8`), here is what to do:

Move `/dev/sda5` 54 GiB to the right, putting the free space between `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda6`.

Move `/dev/sda6` 54 GiB to the right, putting the free space between `/dev/sda6` and `/dev/sda7`.

Move `/dev/sda7` 54 GiB to the right, putting the free space between `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda8`.

Finally, you can expand `/dev/sda8` into the adjacent free space.

This will take a long time (do not do it on battery), and runs the risk of destroying ALL the data on `/dev/sda5`, `/dev/sda6`, `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda8`. Not much of a risk if you are carefull, but I would be remiss if I did not suggest **backup**, **Backup**, **BACKUP**!